# Should the "shenzhou-11" tag be generalized to "shenzhou"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[Shenzhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzou) is China's crewed spacecraft, derived from the Russian Soyuz.  It does not yet have its own tag, but there are currently 19 [questions containing "shenzhou"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=Shenzhou+is%3Aquestion).

[Shenzhou 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhou_11) was a specific flight of the Shenzhou spacecraft.  It has [its own tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shenzhou-11), with 6 questions.

Four questions belong to *both* of the above groups (have "Shenzhou" in the question, and tagged [shenzhou-11](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shenzhou-11)).

We generally don't make tags for specific missions, unless they are so notable as to produce a large number of questions.  There's not much notable about the Shenzhou 11 mission.  However, tags about spacecraft families are very useful.  **Should the [shenzhou-11](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shenzhou-11) tag be renamed [shenzhou](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shenzhou), thus broadening the use of the tag to include questions about the spacecraft family?**

Comment: Rename complete!

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

This seems like a good idea to me.

While many but not all of the Apollo missions do have individual mission tags and a few STS missions do as well, I think these exceptions are for notability and large amount of historical scrutiny and specifics.

For modern launches the mission-specific nature of some tags probably arise because the question is about the specific payload.

In the case of Shenzhou, [falcon-9](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-9) and [falcon-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-heavy) (for example) one tag only should cover the vehicle. Consider that [ariane](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ariane) covers both V and non-V for example, though going forward if here's a VI maybe it will have a new tag.